# How to crop/resize an image to change the aspect ratio using CSS

Tags: javascript, css, html, sass

I have images of size 700px(width) x 333px(height) which have aspect ratio 2.10. I Want to display these images in a grid.The size of each element in the grid is 327px(width)and 183px(height) aspect ratio 1.77.The original images could be cropped or resized with minimum distortion and final aspect ratio of each element should be 1.77 and displayed as 327px(width)and 183px(height).`clip` doesn't work as it "clip"s all other images in the view.Also, there is another background image (like a logo) over which the new images are dynamically rendered.So `background-image:url(img-url);` won't work

How to achieve this through CSS?

Comment: Try CSS **[`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)** for cropping.

Comment: object-fit, clip(), overflow, ... ?  what have you actually tried that did not work ? any code to share ?

Answer (score 2):

Simply use it as a background image and resize it as you need :

```css
div {
  width:327px;
  height:183px;
  background-image:url(https://lorempixel.com/700/333/);
  background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I had to add  `background-position: 50% 50%;` as well

Comment: @dany yes if you want to control what to control what to crop. you can also use `background-position:center`

Answer (score -1):

The aspect is ratio is not quite right 183*1.777=325.191

333/183 = 0.5495 // scale factor - so cropping width

700*.549= 384

384-325=59

crop left and right 30px approx

css

```
div.myimage{
     width: 325px;
     height:183px; 
     }
div.myimage img{ 
       width: 385px;
       height: 183px;
       marginLeft: -30px
       marginRight: -30px;
    }
```