# To crop/resize an image to change the aspect ratio using CSS

Tags: javascript, css, html, image

I have an image of size 700px(width) x 333px(height) which have aspect ratio 2.10. I want to display this image in size 327px(width)and 183px(height) with aspect ratio 16:9.The original images could be cropped or resized with minimum distortion and final aspect ratio of each element should be 16:9 and displayed as 327px(width)and 183px(height).Following is the code I tried.
`object-fit: cover;` works fine, it crops and resizes the image to size 327px X 183px but it is not supported on all/older browsers versions. What could be an alternative to achieve the same result through CSS supported on all and older browsers?

```js
/*original image  :  http://starmoz.com/images/lancia-gamma5.jpg */
```

```css
.cropAndResize {
    width: 327px;
    height: 183px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <img src="http://starmoz.com/images/lancia-gamma5.jpg" class="cropAndResize">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: only with css I don't think you'll get this working on IE Browsers. But have a look here, it's a good polyfill: https://github.com/anselmh/object-fit

Comment: you already posted the same question before : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47760134/how-to-crop-resize-an-image-to-change-the-aspect-ratio-using-css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For crop purpose I often make use of background-image on a element of type block or inline-block instead of relies on img tag:

```css
.cropAndResize {
    width: 327px;
    height: 183px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-image: url('http://starmoz.com/images/lancia-gamma5.jpg');
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="cropAndResize"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: This code gives me the expected result but `background-image` could not be used in this scenario.

Comment: what's your scenario ?

Comment: There is already another image in the background and current image should be placed over it.

Comment: You can always manage the div as image placing it in another div, using inline styles for setting different background-image as you would fill src attributes on an IMG tag

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution could be:

```
.cropAndResize {
  height: 183px;
  margin-left: -20px; 
}

div {
  width: 327px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: It is 327 px, but the image is not centered. That's why it looks different. You could add margin-left: -20px;  to the .cropandresize in css

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this could work for you? The only caveat is you need to set a specific margin to align the image within the container to center it.

```css
.crop {
    width: 327px;
    height: 183px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.cropAndResize {
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: 0px 0px 0 -20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="crop">
    <img src="http://starmoz.com/images/lancia-gamma5.jpg" class="cropAndResize">
  </div>
</body>
```